# Add textviews in layout side by side

Tags: android

I need to create universal layout where I will add textviews side by side in horizontal view and when I have a lot of textviews for single line they will shows in second line. 
I can use one textview in linear layout but every word should have rounded different color background and I don't know if this is possible to create one big string where every word have different background. Any ideas how resolve problem?

Comment: How's about flow layout? https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: that is solution for me. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google's FlexboxLayout, it will fulfill the requirement

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

try this, So many examples available for that..